How to Convert Local Image file to Blurred Image File in Android Fastly withing 5seconds
I'm working on an Android project where I need to perform some high-performance computations (e.g., image processing, matrix operations). I was using RenderScript to achieve this, but recently I encountered a warning saying that RenderScript is deprecated.
//passing local image file need to generate blurred version
fun blurrImageGenerateThumbnail(file:File){
    
}



Related: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/migrate
